# chrome browser's scrollbar "overlaps" UI instead of pushing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

[image]

In the screenshot above, Firefox and Edge displays the UI properly. However in Chrome, as circled in the screenshot, the scrollbar "overlaps" the UI. How do I prevent Chrome from "overlapping" the UI. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your code in the snippet?

Comment: Have you tried to target the specific browser to style it ( margin right) through @media rule

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution. Set `overflow: auto` on the body. I think its good practice to put `overflow: auto` if you set the body's height/min-height to 100%